# Select Attribiute B where Attribiute A is maximal after groupby in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Given the following table:

| ID | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | a |
| 1 | 42 | b |
| 2 | 34 | a |

I would like to have one row per `ID` where the price was maximal

| ID | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | b |
| 2 | 34 | a |

Trying to groupby `ID` and selecting `ID, Date, MAX(Price)` results in the error `GROUP BY clause with non aggregate functions`

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/11683)

Comment: teradata (edited), but I'm capabile of adapting from postgresql

Comment: Yes, it does. My post is a duplicate of that post. I wasn't able to find it. thanks.

Comment: Press the big blue button then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
your_table_name
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by price desc) = 1;
```

> The Qualify clause is used to filter the results of ordered analytical
> function according to user‑specified search conditions. We can use
> this conditional clause in the SELECT statement to get the particular
> order values.